# Cannot Add User on KDE Neon User Edition Live

Tags: kde, settings, kde-neon

I've been learning Linux with Ubuntu 18.04 but recently I wanted to try out a different desktop environment compared to GNOME. So I decided to run a Live version of KDE Neon 5.16.0( released 13 June 2019 ). After playing around with the panels and pre-installed applications I wanted to create a user account for myself with administrator privileges. But it seems that I can't escape being a Live session user. User Manager doesn't seem to save my new user details after I click Apply. I also tried rebooting Neon just to see if that would work but to no avail. It would be nice to have a static user account so I can save my progress, because every reboot seems to just be a refreshed Live session user account. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious to KDE environments.

Comment: This happens because it is a live system which is not persistent - meaning any changes you make will only happen in memory and be gone after a reboot.

Comment: @Panki Ah ok I thought as much since live is usually just to test out the OS. I was using Bodhi live before this as well and assumed my setting changes were saved but never checked thereafter. Thanks alot.

Comment: Instead of using Live USBs or whatever, why not do an install as a virtual machine? Depending on your machine's specs, you may not get all of the fancy desktop effects, but otherwise VMs are a nice way to learn.

Comment: @DK Bose I definitely am going to set that up on my home system in time, and with the specs my current machine runs I think it'll do justice with each distro. But I just wanted to try some of the distros out on flash drives since I could just carry them around with my laptop for now. So to solve the volatile memory and refreshed profile that happens every time, I came across mkusb to create 'persistent' live versions, and did this with KDE Neon 5.16.0. Now I can save my changes. It's the best option really that I've came across so far when it comes to a real portable experience.

Answer (score 0):

Following commentary above, indeed because of it being a Live usb the changes made to it will not be saved when it's shut down and not powered. As such the Live edition will also not be able to create new accounts because it is limited to Live User Session profiles for testing purposes.